# Dynamic binding == late binding in Java or not?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

In different sources i've read different things on the topic. For example Wikipedia says:

> Late binding is often confused with dynamic dispatch, but there are significant differences.

But a couple lines later

> it is popular to use the term late binding in Java programming as a synonym for dynamic dispatch. Specifically, this refers to Java's single dispatch mechanism used with virtual methods.

So where's the truth and what are this "significant differences"?

Comment: Are you referring to Lazy loading?

Comment: @bmoran: No. He's talking about a more fundamental language level thing. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Late binding and dynamic single dispatch are, for all intents and purposes, the same. In dynamic single dispatch, the value or identity of a single object determines which code is invoked at runtime, and that's what happens in Java.

The term *dynamic dispatch* in general is most often used to imply dynamic *multiple* dispatch, which is where the runtime method is chosen at runtime based on the identities or values of *more than one object*, which is a language feature in CLOS and Smalltalk, but not in Java or C++.

Comment: +1, but I'd characterize "late binding" as the fully late bound invocation of a language like Python, while Java's model of dynamic single dispatch is actually a partially-early, partially-late binding, much more like C++ virtual methods.

Comment: I had assumed that invoke dynamic added in Java 7 performed dynamic dispatch. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/DynTypeLang/ What is the difference?

Comment: @DanielPryden -- indeed, I'd agree with that. What you're calling "fully late bound," I call "duck typing"; this is basically method-based rather than type-based lookup.

Comment: @PeterLawrey -- yeah, that's "duck typing". It's being able to send a message at runtime without any requirements on the type of the recipient. The Java language itself doesn't include this concept, but the Java 7 JVM does support it (and Java now weakly supports it through reflection-like API classes.)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: Yeah, I think "late binding" (in the fullest sense) and "duck typing" are basically the same thing.  The only distinction I might make between them is that I think of "late binding" as a *language* feature, while "duck typing" is a more abstract thing, basically just a programming mindset.  But I'll admit that that's a pretty fine hair to split.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Could you please make an example of dynamic multiple dispatch in Smalltalk?

Comment: Smalltalk does not have multiple dynamic dispatch to my knowledge, only single.