# C++ late binding (dynamic binding)

Tags: c++, types, rtti

AFAIK C++ only supports Dynamic single dispatch but doesn't support late binding ***syntactically*** like VB does

```
Dim x As Object
Set x = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Debug.Print x.GetSpecialFolder(0).
```

But it has methods to achieve that, eg.

```
std::cout << typeid(*ptr).name() << std::endl;
```

Is my understanding right?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Please add some example code, preferably a [mcve], to more clearly describe what you are asking.

Comment: Given your example in VB, I would say, Yes your understanding of dynamic dispatch in C++ is correct. It's not clear to me what you mean by *But it has methods to achieve that*.

Comment: I'm trying to understand late binding and how it's different from dynamic dispatch. I understand that as postponing everything to runtime. Which means, the compiler doesn't have any info about an object's type on which we call some function. So, it can't check whether that function even exists. The only thing to do is wait till the program executes and see what class the objects belongs to and then make the validation.

Comment: And VB for example has syntax for this cause you can say Dim obj as Object, and call a function on obj. But C++ doesn't have syntax for this(in other words doesn't support this feature) but we can simulate this through the code I gave above. Is this analogy right? Or RTTI and that example I gave in C++ is something different?

Comment: The difference between late binding and dynamic dispatch is explained in [What is the difference between dynamic dispatch and late binding in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187587/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-dispatch-and-late-binding-in-c). I am tempted to close your question a duplicate of the other post.